# Can I return auto from a std::visit?

Tags: c++

```cpp
//type description example
class TextComponent_type : public _type 
{
public: 
using type = TextComponent; 
static constexpr uInt value = 3;
};
//...

//ECSData member functions

template<uInt id>
    auto& getVector()
    {
        return std::visit([this] (auto&& T_type)->(auto&) {
                    using T = typename std::decay_t<decltype(T_type)>::type;    
                    return _getVectorFromT<T>();
                           }, dataMapping[id]);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>& _getVectorFromT()
    {
        void* voidPtr = data[decltype(T::type)::value].get();
        std::vector<T>* vec = static_cast<std::vector<T>*>(voidPtr);
        return *vec;
    }
```

In the code above I have a function meant to be called with a number, like `getVector<3>()`, the class with that member function has a std::map member variable called dataMapping which as Key has a number and as Value a std::variant holding simple structs that describe a type and the associated value (//type description example class on top of the code)

So I am visiting this variant to retrieve the associated type and passing it to `_getVectorFromT()` to be able to cast to the correct type and return it to the caller, in this example case the return would be a `std::vector<TextComponent>&`

But the code is not compiling at all, here the complete code if you want to try yourself https://godbolt.org/z/Tq32jm

So as the title says, can I return auto& from std::visit?
I need this because the return could be any of `std::vector<RectComponent>&`, `std::vector<ConstraintComponent>&`, `std::vector<TextComponent>&` etc...

Comment: All lambdas should return types that have some common type. You can't return distinct unrelated types.

Comment: `std::visit` returns a concrete type. Full stop. `auto` can be used to achieve that goal, but the end result must be a type that's deducible at compile-time.

Comment: is this idea of a type stored in a variant idea a dead end then? Or there is a way for me to still leverage this and return the correct vector type given an int?

Comment: Rule of thumb: a type of an expression can only depend on something that is known at compile-time.  `dataMapping[id].index()` is only known at runtime, so the return type can't depend on it.

Comment: No. The "correct vector type" must be a discrete type. It can, itself, be a `std::variant`, that the visitor constructs with the appropriate variant member.

Comment: This still works one way though, for instance a `removeComponent<2>(12)` would remove component id 12 from vector 2.
So if anyone has any suggestion to make this also work the opposite way (to retrieve a vector using this) any idea is welcome

Comment: You are basically re-implementing `std::tuple<std::vector<Args>...>`. Why not use that?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to do this is not possible - the type must be inferred at compile time.

`dataMapping[id]` returns the same type - you could turn this part into a traits-like based design ala.

```
template<int id>
struct dataMapping;

template<>
struct dataMapping<0> {
  using type = int; //... or whatever
}
//and so on
```

Comment: already tried, lead to a problem where I can't remove all components belonging to an entity like this:
```
for (auto it = entity.components.begin(); it!= entity.components.end(); it++)
  {
   using T = idType<it->first>;
   for (auto compId : it->second) {
    removeComponent<T>(compId);
   }
  }
```
line `using T = idType<it->first>;` is not valid because has to be known at compile time, my whole solution is meant to play around this

Comment: @MarcusAseth then it is not possible with auto keyword (which must evaluate compile-time)